# Морфемный разбор слова "награда"

Tags: морфемика

Помогите разобрать слово "награда" по составу. В "Словаре морфем русского языка" А.И.Кузнецовой, Т.Ф.Ефремовой приставка ***НА-.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А. И. Кузнецовв и Т. Ф. Ефремова не правы,

в слове "награда", как и "народ", корень *-град-/-род-* не выделяется: приставка (историческая) срослась с корнем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если онлайн-разбор не аргумент супротив авторитетного словаря, есть и [другие источники](https://refdb.ru/look/1252739-pall.html):

> Для правильного понимания смысла слов, точного их употребления
>   необходимо разбираться в составе слова. Главное состоит в том, чтобы
>   разбор слова по составу не проходил ме­ханически, когда всю работу по
>   составу слов сводят к умению выделить корень, а это приводит к
>   механическому разрубанию слова на куски, к выделе­нию корня только
>   потому, что похожий звуковой комплекс слышится и в другом случае
>   (награда и град).

---

> ...Сюда входят слова, **родственные отношения между которыми уже не
>   может ни увидеть, ни даже «почувствовать» никто, ибо произошел
>   реальный разрыв родственных отношений, произошла деэтимологизация
>   слов**; для обнаружения исторически существовавших родственных связей
>   в таких случаях надо знать историю русского языка и применять
>   специальные аналитические процедуры, выработанные этимологической
>   наукой. К этой группе можно отнести такие случаи:
>
> благоухать – нюхать,
>
> бодрый – бдеть,
>
> брак – брать,
>
> вспылить – пылать,
>
> вьюга – вить,
>
> добыть – быть,
>
> досуг – досягать,
>
> ряд – заряд,
>
> острый – изощрить,
>
> изъять – изящный,
>
> тяга – истязать;
>
> колесо – колея – около,
>
> награда – град / город,
>
> польза – легкий – льгота
>
> и другие.

**[источник](http://taldaev.com29.ru/lib/lzheimennoe_slovoobrazovanie.pdf)**

---

Ещё один **[словарь](http://www.bravica.ws/ru/morphemic-spelling/word_36793.htm)**, который, минуя "награду", разбирает по морфемам слово "наградной":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В заключение - [цитата из Фасмера](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]